# Odata query returns 401

Tags: date-time, choice-field, odata, 401, sharepoint-server

I'm working with the SharePoint 2016 OnPremis OData Rest Api. The filter parameter is defined followings:
`$filter=Art/Value eq 'aString' and year(Received) eq 2019`

Art is a choice value and Received is a datetime.

```
baseurl = http://portal/website/subsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/myList
```

`baseurl  --> works`
`baseurl  + ?$select=ID --> works`
`baseurl  + ?$select=ID&$filter=year(Received) eq 2019 --> 401`
`baseurl  + ?$select=ID&$filter=Art/Value eq 'aString' --> 401`
`baseurl  + ?$select=ID&$filter=Art/Value eq 'aString' and year(Received) eq 2019 --> 401`

Calls are done in Chrome and IE, so the credentials are present.
Any idea whats going on?
If e.g. I filter on an integer, it works.

Further tests:
`baseUrl + ?$select=Created --> works`
`baseUrl + ?$select=Created&$filter=year(Created) eq 2010 --> 401`

Comment: What is an error you are getting? can you post the exact error? And for choice, I guess  you can directly use `$filter=Art eq 'aString'`.

Comment: What error? I get an 401...
No, if I write `$filter=Art eq 'aString'` I get `Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity' and 'System.String'`

Comment: Are your examples complete? I.e. does your URL include $expand?

Comment: As far as i know, the $expand is only needed for lookups, not for choices.

Comment: have you solved the 401 error?

Comment: I didn't, I gave up. I created an endpoint where I do my query using CSOM and return the elements properly.